# Как вытащить отдельный канал из трехканального изображения, лежащего в Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

У меня есть цветное изображение, хранящееся в объекте класса Mat. И есть в функция, в которую нужно последовательно передать каждый из каналов этого объекта. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел: функция split разделяет многоканальное изображение на массив одноканальных:

```
void split(const Mat& src, Mat* mvbegin)
void split(InputArray m, OutputArrayOfArrays mv)
```